# How to prevent a method from being called if another one wasn't called before

Tags: c#

I'm working with C# for three days now, so excuse my noobish question please.

I'm trying to build an own database class which shall contain, among other things, a method for sendig select-statements.

How do i prevent this method from being called, when `connect()` wasn't invoked before by the object? I thought about a simple boolean variable, but this is, in my opinion, a very ugly solution.

Comment: -1 for externally hosted code (typically because it means it's *very long*). Just copy and paste *the relevant portion* here.

Comment: If you get a Connection object, why not just check if it's null? If it is, then don't call your function.

Comment: If you need to do that, the way is a boolean flag and `throw new InvalidOperationException()`. That's ugly indeed, which should be a hint that you either *really* need to do it or else (usually) it's a bad idea. I also recommend that you immediately change your security credentials on the server.

Comment: Excuse me, but for a complete class overview, to tell me if this is good or bad code, the complete code is necessary, isn't it?

my actual question has no sample code because the method does not exist yet

Comment: @Sprottenwels Fair enough, perhaps you would be better to post the complete class overview on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ though. IMHO, code that long on SO smells of "too localized".

Comment: @lc.
good point. Didn't even know about that site. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Separate out the idea of "something which is capable of connecting" from "a live connection which is capable of running a query".

Make your `Connect` method (you should *really* start following [.NET naming conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229045.aspx) by the way) return something which you can query.

That way each class is responsible for one job, and you avoid the concept of trying to query before connecting from even being *represented* in code.

Comment: Where should the Disconnect method go? Same place as the Connect method, passing it the live connection/"something you can query"?

Comment: @Tur1ng: This question is over 10 years old, and I didn't even suggest a Disconnect method in the answer... I don't really want to get into additional variations.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a State field that stores the state and use that. In this simple example I've got a boolean **Connected** (True / False) but you could have an `enum` with Connected, Disconnected, Faulted etc.

```
private bool _Connected = false;

public bool Connect()
{
    // ...
    if (success)
    {
        _Connected = true;
    }
}

public bool Disconnect()
{
    // ...

    _Connected = false;
}

public IEnumberable<Data> GetData()
{
    if (!_Connected)
    {
        // Handle not connected here...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of a boolean.

just do something like:

```
if (con == NULL || !con.isOpen())
{
    // throw an exception or return
}
```

simple and allways prevents you from access to the con object if something go wrong.